# How to mute specific sounds when using multiple audio inputs using P5 Amplitude (P5.js)

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js, visualizer, p5.sound.js

I'm very much a P5.js newbie so apologies if this is obvious.

I'm trying to build a music visualiser type animation where the amplitude of different audio files control various parameters. However I only want the use to hear the audio file containing the full mastered track.

In this simple example I want the amplitude of the 'kick', 'Hats_1' and 'tb303' files to control the size of the 3 circles. However I don't want these sounds to be output to the speakers (essentially they would be muted, but the amplitude still usable) - instead I only want the user to hear the file 'full track clip'.

`

```
let kick, kick_amp;
let hats_1, hats_1_amp;
let tb303, tb303_amp;
let full_track, full_track_amp;
let smoothing = 0.4;

function preload() {
  kick = loadSound('kick.mp3'); 
  hats_1 = loadSound('Hats 1.mp3'); 
  tb303 = loadSound('303.mp3'); 
  full_track = loadSound('full track clip.mp3'); 
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600)

  kick.play();  
  kick_amp = new p5.Amplitude();
  kick_amp.setInput(kick);
  kick_amp.smooth(smoothing);
  
  hats_1.play();  
  hats_1_amp = new p5.Amplitude();
  hats_1_amp.setInput(hats_1);
  kick_amp.smooth(smoothing);

  tb303.play();  
  tb303_amp = new p5.Amplitude();
  tb303_amp.setInput(tb303);
  tb303_amp.smooth(smoothing);

  full_track.play();  
  full_track_amp = new p5.Amplitude();
  full_track_amp.setInput(full_track);
  full_track_amp.smooth(smoothing);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  let kick_vol = kick_amp.getLevel();
  ellipse( width*0.25,height/2, kick_vol*100, kick_vol*100);

  let hats_1_vol = hats_1_amp.getLevel();
  ellipse(width*0.75, height/2, hats_1_vol*100, hats_1_vol*100);

  let tb303_vol = tb303_amp.getLevel();
  ellipse(width*0.5, height*0.25, tb303_vol*100, tb303_vol*100);

}

// Click on the web page to start audio 
function touchStarted() {
  getAudioContext().resume();
}
```

`

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

I've tried looking through the P5.Amplitude reference and searching SO but no dice.